# DBcontext.SaveChanges keeps returning 0 when updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm currently trying to do a really simple function that updates a category using LINQ. However dbContext.SaveChanges() always returns 0 rows updated even when I hardcode the categoryId to update which is really frustrating. I've already tried many forms of debugging but fail to find the problem. If anyone can help me figure out my dumb mistake, it would be greatly appreciated!

Things I've tried,
- Trying to see if row with that category_Id exists, always returns 1 which is correct.

```
    var count = (from c in dbContext.RecipeCategories
                      where c.Category_Id == categoryToEdit
                      select c).Count();
```

Removing myCategory instead of trying to update it, works as well. It seems like only the update does not work.

```
    dbContext.RecipeCategories.Remove(myCateogry);
```

My DALayer for category functions

```
    public bool EditCategory(int categoryToEdit, RecipeCategory newCategoryInfo)
    {
        RecipeXchangeDBContext dbContext = new RecipeXchangeDBContext();
        RecipeCategory myCategory = new RecipeCategory();
        bool status = false;

        myCategory = (from c in dbContext.RecipeCategories
                      where c.Category_Id == categoryToEdit
                      select c).First();

        myCategory.Category_Name = newCategoryInfo.Category_Name;
        myCategory.Description = newCategoryInfo.Description;
        myCategory.CatGroup_Id = newCategoryInfo.CatGroup_Id;

        try
        {
            if (dbContext.SaveChanges() == 1)
                status = true;
            else
                status = false;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
```

My attempt to call the function, always goes to else block, dbContext.SaveChanges() returns 0 with no exceptions thrown.

```
    protected void btnEditCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["categoryId"] != null)
        {
            CategoryDAL categoryDAL = new CategoryDAL();
            RecipeCategory myCategory = new RecipeCategory();
            try
            {
                addDiv.Attributes["class"] = "hidden";
                editDiv.Attributes["class"] = "display";

                int categoryToEdit = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["categoryId"]);

                myCategory.Category_Name = tbEditCategoryName.Text;
                myCategory.Description = tbEditCategoryDescription.Text;
                myCategory.CatGroup_Id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEditCategoryGroupList.SelectedValue);

                try
                {
                    bool editStatus = categoryDAL.EditCategory(categoryToEdit, myCategory);
                    if (editStatus)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["editStatus"] = "Successful";
                        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/ManageCategories.aspx");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        lblEditStatus.Text = "Unable to update category, please try again";
                        lblEditStatus.CssClass = "alert-danger";
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblEditStatus.Text = Convert.ToString(ex);
                    lblEditStatus.CssClass = "alert-danger";
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                updateStatus.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-info alert-dismissable fade in";
                updateStatus.Visible = true;
                lblStatus.Text = "Invalid categoryId.";
            }

        }

        else
        {
            updateStatus.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-info alert-dismissable fade in";
            updateStatus.Visible = true;
            lblStatus.Text = "Nothing to update.";
        }
    }
```

Update ** Seems like this is what's causing the problem. If the values of the form are prepopulated it doesn't seem to allow me to update the object. If I comment out the part where it populates the form. The update function works normally. Can anyone help me figure out why prepopulating the form causes the update to fail?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate Edit Fields
        if (Request.QueryString["categoryId"] != null)
        {
            CategoryDAL categoryDAL = new CategoryDAL();
            RecipeCategory myCategory = new RecipeCategory();
            try
            {
                addDiv.Attributes["class"] = "hidden";
                editDiv.Attributes["class"] = "display";

                int categoryToGet = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["categoryId"]);
                myCategory = categoryDAL.GetCategory(categoryToGet);

                tbEditCategoryName.Text = myCategory.Category_Name;
                tbEditCategoryDescription.Text = myCategory.Description;

                ddlEditCategoryGroupList.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(myCategory.CatGroup_Id);
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                updateStatus.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-info alert-dismissable fade in";
                updateStatus.Visible = true;
                lblStatus.Text = "Could not get Category Info, please try again.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the data change in the db?

Comment: It doesn't :(, it changes for remove and add though.

Comment: If the properties you set are the same as the original values in the database record, no update will be performed and `SaveChanges` will return 0. This is normal for such type of update.

Comment: When I click edit it will link me to a form that allows me to edit the fields. For example, if I change the descriptions, it still returns 0.

Comment: The form is populated first using the id from query string which proves that the "Category_Id" exists.

Comment: Are you sure `dbContext.SaveChanges()` returns 0 and not a number greater than 1?

Comment: I tried changing if(dbContext.SaveChanges() == 0) status = true; and it returned true.

Comment: And if it was returning a number greater than 1, the database should have updated I think.

Comment: What is the PK of the objects updated?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro just Category_Id

Comment: That's strange. Check if `dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is `true`. Or if calling `dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` before `SaveChanges` helps.

Comment: @IvanStoev Where do I check that setting?

Comment: In your DAL class - after `RecipeXchangeDBContext dbContext = new RecipeXchangeDBContext();`

Comment: Then I don't this I have either of those configuration. The code above is a direct snippet of the function

Comment: Any database triggers involved? Anything in an override of `SaveChanges` in `RecipeXchangeDBContext` (I ask just to be sure, not knowing if this is all your own code).

Comment: Nope no changes made, everything should be default.

Comment: I've even tried doing an update query using an sql statement and it works, it seems that its just the SaveChanges() bugging out and returning 0 when I try to update.

Comment: Do you have ChangeTracking enabled? what happens when you set the state of myCategory to modified manually?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro How can I check if ChangeTracking is enabled. What do you mean modified manually?

Comment: it is the context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled property. If it is true, ChangeTracking is enabled. You can set the state of an attached object by setting context.Entry(myCategory).State=EntityState.Modified.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I added what I think is the Configuartion for the DbContext, I don't think I have AutoDetectChanges Enabled. Should I change anything here??

Comment: either enable ChangeTracking for your operation (and turn it back off afterwards) or set state state of the entry to modified manually.

Comment: also, what you added is not the configuration of your context, it's the model.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I'm not sure where to set the ChangeTracking? I have the following in my edmx
.Context.tt, 
.Context.cs, 
.Designer.cs, 
.Model.tt

Comment: Can you please try `dbContext.Update(newCategoryInfo); dbContext.SaveChanges();`?

Comment: @Mithgroth There's no method called Update.

Comment: @KelvinGamer can you add your model class to the question? And try to add the following line of code before `dbContext.SaveChanges()`: `dbContext.SetModified(myCategory)`

Comment: @rufer7 The problem has been solved. I was populating my form in my onLoad function without postback. Thanks for all the responses!!